# Split density plot in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

How can I do a density plot that is split across variables like the ones done in Figure 1 in this paper ? https://www.pnas.org/content/117/24/13386

Obivously, doing geom_density on filtered data then changes the value of the density towards the border, because it assumes zeroes right after 1.96 if coming from the left.

What I'd need is to compute the whole density, but only plot half of it

Comment: Why don't you calculate density by hand and just plot the part you're interested in?

Comment: The authors of the paper you cited used `rddensity` package for the analysis and plots.